Source Code: Type assertion to anonymous interface with different numbers of parameters
Please, forgive me, I'm a newbee of learning golang, and there is one line code in golang source code, errors package wrap.go file. make me so confusing.
golang version: v1.22.5;
package: errors;
file name: wrap.go;
code line: 53-78;
func is(err, target error, targetComparable bool) bool {
  for {
    if targetComparable && err == target {
      return true
    }
    
    // confusing line below
    if x, ok := err.(interface{ Is(error) bool }); ok && x.Is(target) {
      return true
    }
    

    // rest of lines
  }
}

My confusing is:

The errors package method errors.Is(err, target error) bool  has two parameters, how could it type assert to a anonymous interface with function which only have one errorparameters?
Is there any other exception allow such thing happen?

here is a example, I'm trying to verify.


The errors package method errors.Is(err, target error) bool has two parameters, how could it type assert to a anonymous interface with function which only have one error parameters?

You're right - it can't! This isn't trying to do anything with the errors.Is function, it's trying to check if err implements it's own way to determine if it is another error. From the dcoumentation:

An error type might provide an Is method so it can be treated as equivalent to an existing error. For example, if MyError defines
func (m MyError) Is(target error) bool { return target == fs.ErrExist }
then Is(MyError{}, fs.ErrExist) returns true.

The Is function that the code you cite is looking for only has one parameter because the other parameter is replaced by the value that it is called on (err).

The line of code implements the following feature described in the  errors.Is documentation:

An error type might provide an Is method so it can be treated as equivalent to an existing error. For example, if MyError defines
func (m MyError) Is(target error) bool { return target == fs.ErrExist }

then Is(MyError{}, fs.ErrExist) returns true.

The statement
if x, ok := err.(interface{ Is(error) bool }); ok && x.Is(target) {
  return true
}

uses a type assertion to determine whether err has an Is(error) bool method.  If err has the method, then the method is called.  If the method returns true, then errors.Is returns true.
The code in the playground example fails to compile because errInterfaceImpl{} is not an interface type.  Try this instead.
